# Using negative margin to adhere div1 to the left of div2

Tags: html, css, margin

I want to adhere a dismiss button to the left of the contact in a sidebar, like shown in this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJE3h.png

But after using `margin-left: -50px;` or `left: -50px;`, the `dismiss` div disappears! Its position is correct by inspecting the element but I don't know how to show it as normal, which should be a purple square.

The full demo is: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YbpZaV

#### HTML

```
<nav class="sidebar">
  <div class="dismiss">dismiss</div>
  <div class="contacts">
</nav>
```

#### CSS

```
.sidebar {
  width: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  z-index: 40;
}

.dismiss {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #7386d5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  z-index: 40;
}
```

Comment: delete `position: fixed;` in your sidebar and it will reappear

Comment: Your `sidebar` container needs `overflow-x: visible`

Comment: demo here https://jsfiddle.net/49vmr061/ please  remove overflow-x: visible

Comment: Removing `overflow-y: auto;` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove `overflow-y: auto` :-

```
    .sidebar {
    width: 250px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;      
    transition: all 0.3s;
    z-index: 40;
    }
```